# PostGIS - raster - get multiple values at once

Tags: postgis, raster

Is there a way, how to obtain more points from raster in one query faster than this?

```
SELECT x, y, ST_Value(raw_data, 1, x, y) AS val_0, 
      ST_Value(raw_data, 2, x, y) AS val_1 
FROM data 
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, 256) As x 
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, 256) As y 
WHERE ((x = 184 AND y = 192) OR (x = 185 AND y = 192) OR ....)
```

Speed of this is the same as if I call `ST_Value` for every pair manually (but that is not, what I want)

Also, I have two bands and need value from both. But ifthere is something faster for only one band data, I can separate them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will be faster if you don't generate series of rows but rather pre-define the data you want to join with.

```
WITH pairs(x,y) AS (
    VALUES
    (184,192)
    ,(185,192)
) 
SELECT 
  x
  ,y
  ,ST_Value(raw_data, 1, x, y) AS val_0
  ,ST_Value(raw_data, 2, x, y) AS val_1 
FROM 
    data
    CROSS JOIN pairs
```

Comment: I have created some performance comparison - your query vs single query N times - http://www.perry.cz/clanky/postgis.html

Comment: @MartinPerry I don't understand why you tried to use `ST_ConvexHull` in an index there, You probably should expand that bit.

Answer (score 1):

I think the revized version of the query as follows may perform better, is it?

```
WITH pairs(x,y) AS (
    VALUES
    (70.5084, 45.1985),
    (70.5094, 45.1995),
    (70.5084, 45.1975),
    (70.5074, 45.1965),
    (70.5064, 45.1955),
    (70.5054, 45.1945)
) 
SELECT 
  ST_Value(rast, ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x, y), 4326)) AS height
FROM dem_raster rs
    CROSS JOIN pairs
    WHERE ST_Intersects(rs.rast,  ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(x, y), 4326));
```